# Linear Algebra Polynomial Subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $P_n$ be the set of polynomials of degree at most $n$ with real coefficients. Is the set of polynomials of the form $p(t) = a + t^2,$ such that '$a$' is an element of $\mathbb{R},$ a subspace of $P_n?$

I know I need to check if it contains the zero vector first. How would I do this? I have two ideas:

$1.$ plug $0$ into '$a$' and have a function $g(t) = t^2$ then add it to $p(t)$ to get $p(t) + g(t) = a + 2t^2$ which is not in the form, or

$2.$ plug $0$ into '$a$' and also for the coefficient of $t^2?$

Thanks!

Comment: Check if it's closed under vector addition.

Comment: What is the $0$ in $P_n$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $V$ be a vector space and $W\subset V$. We want $W$ to satisfy three key axioms for it to fit the definition of subspace.

$1$. $\{0\}\in W$

$2$. $w_1+w_2=w_3\in W$ (closure under vector addition)

$3$. $cw\in W$ (closure under scalar multiplication)

For the subset of polynomials $W$ defined by $p(t)=a+t^2$, we don't have closure under addition, because we have $p(t)+q(t)=(a+b)+2t^2$, which is not of the desired form.

also, the set fails closure under scalar multiplication as well, since $cp(t)=c(a+t^2)=ca+ct^2$. The only exception is $c=1$, but $W$ still fails the vector addition axiom so it is not a subspace.

Finally, the zero vector (and for polynomials, the **zero polynomial** -that whose all coefficients $a_0, a_1,..., a_n = 0$, and in this case, only $a = 0$) is also not in the subset except for the single case where $t=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Both of your two ideas work and are indeed based on the fact that the polynomial set of that form is not closed under addition(obvious, for $t^2+t^2=2t^2$). Hence it's not a subspace.

Comment: idea 2. will give me g(t) = 0 + 0^2 and then using this ile find g(t) + p(t) = p(t) so then it works, so which do I do? i get two completely different conclusions

Comment: If you put $a=0$ you get $t^2$ in the set and so is $2t^2$ while it is not of the form required.

Answer (score -1):

The zero element $P_n$ is not in the set, but I feel some clarification to the above statements is necessary:
The zero of this space is the polynomial with all zero coefficients - not the polynomial that equals zero when you set $t=0$. Thus, multiplication by the zero polynomial will result in zero for all vectors (i.e., other polynomials) in this space. You never really plug in a number for $t$ when dealing with questions on this space, the vectors are the polynomial equations themselves.
This is enough to conclude it is not a vector space, but it's also true that the set is not closed under vector addition or scalar multiplication as well, as outlined above.